# Javascript regex without lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript and trying to match mathematical functions such as f(2) or g(1200) but not match things like sqrt(2)

Right now I have

```
/[a-z]\([\d]+\)/
```

and that highlights these on regexr

- **g(2)**
- **f(2)**
- f(x)
- **f(2)** **g(3)**
- sqr**t(2)**

everything is perfect except I don't want that part of sqrt to be selected. I want to lookbehind for letters but javascript doesn't support that, any idea on how I can work around this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a word boundary:

```
\b[a-z]\(\d+\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX7dW5/1)

Since JS regex engine does not support a lookbehind, a logical way out is to utilize a word boundary assertion here: if the letter matched with `[a-z]` is not preceded with a word character (one from the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` range), it is OK to match it - that is when `\b` comes in very handy.

Alsom, you do not have to place the only shorthand character class pattern into a character class, `[\d]` will match the same characters as `\d`.